# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

i have a kafkaflink job which works in intellij, on packaging with sbt i get the below message

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
```

Thanks for having a look at it

Comment: Please show your dependencies and classpath

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly have Kafka as `provided` dependency or you are not creating the fat-jar.

You need to use a plugin depending on the build tool You are using for sbt it can be `sbt assembly`, for maven it can be `maven-shade-plugin`. And then You need to have flink-kafka-connector in compile scope.